# Image (img) tag returns 404 and a default image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

***my Image tag***

```
<img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/Q9p-UGqlRMg/mqdefault.jpg">
```

**i tried this ( this works with the rest of 404 image URLs but not with youtube thumbnail url )**

```
$('img').on('error', function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'http://i.giphy.com/9J7tdYltWyXIY.gif');    // show a fallback image if there is an error
});
```

and

```
<img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/Q9p-UGqlRMg/mqdefault.jpg" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://placeimg.com/200/300/animals';">
```

I guess youtube already returning a default 404 image, that might be a reason.

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you asking how to detect youtube returning the fallback image instead of the actual thumbnail?

Comment: Maybe GET request to non-existing resource is intercepted by YT and image is replaced by their "404 image". Have you tried making HEAD call to the image before loading? You should get 404 HttpCode response if it doesnt exists and will have opportunity to load your own image.

Comment: YT responds with a 404 status code for this URL, but because it also sends an actual image in the response, browsers appear to display the image, rather than trigger the error handler. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#image_loading_errors lists a couple of situations when the error handler should trigger, but the HTTP status code isn’t even mentioned there (although that list does not claim to be exclusive.)

Comment: It does not look like those resources were CORS-enabled either though, meaning a client-side HEAD request would likely also not work, you’d have to do this check on the server side then.

Comment: @ChrisG YES, in my page i show youtube thumbnails, some thumbnails return 404 and default thumbnail (https://img.youtube.com/vi/Q9p-UGqlRMg/mqdefault.jpg)

Comment: @KarolPawlak hmm.. good idea, can u please show me how

Comment: @CBroe that is my last option to do it on server side, but that would surely increase TTFB as there are thousands of thumbnails

Answer (score 1):

you forget the extension file ??

```
https://placeimg.com/200/300/animals.jpg
```

try this

```
<img src="http://example.com/non-existent-image.jpg" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://placeimg.com/200/300/animals6';" />
```

Comment: https://placeimg.com is a website that returns placeholder images with specific category and dimensions. Its an endpoint, not specific file. There is no need to add extension to the name of the category

Comment: @KarolPawlak true

Answer (score 1):

YouTube answers will not fire the onerror() function because YouTube sends image which shows the gray video icon. The approach, knowing dimensions of the returned image is to detect it and replace it with our backup image. Try running snippet below:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.youtube-thumb').each(function(ix, it){
    if($(it)[0].naturalHeight <= 90 ) {
      var path = $(it).attr('src').replace('https://img.youtube.com/vi/Q9p-UGqlRMg/mqdefault.jpg','https://placeimg.com/200/300/animals');
      
      $(it).attr('src', path);
    }
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<img class="youtube-thumb" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/Q9p-UGqlRMg/mqdefault.jpg" border="1" height="100" alt="image" />
</div>
```

Or to handle every image in the time of loading it instead of waiting for all and iterating over them:

```js
$(function() {

  var img = document.querySelector('img');

  if (img.complete) {
    check404(img)
  } else {
    img.addEventListener('load', check404)
  }
  
});

function check404(img) {

if(img.naturalHeight <= 90 ) {
  img.src = 'https://placeimg.com/200/300/animals';
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/Q9p-UGqlRMg/mqdefault.jpg" border="1" height="100" alt="image" />
</div>
```

Comment: whoa  , that's a smart move. I will implement this for now. But there should be a proper way to do this.

Comment: If you don't want to be dependent on dimensions, there is another approach, Knowing the image returned with 404 status, you can base64 encode it, and save the string. Than compare every incoming image with this string to check if its the "non-existing image placeholder" or the image you are expecting. Nothing else comes to my mind as you need simple and fast solution to implement on client side (JS)

Comment: encodeing every image out of thousands to base64, comparing and then displaying the non-404 images, on the client-side. don't you think this is Harsh.

Comment: Yes of course. Its just another way, never said its the best one :)

Comment: The only "proper" way to do this and handle this errors is to use YouTube API, but in your case if you only want to modify client side its not possible.